# Getting counts of donors grouped into categories by giving amount

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

Let's say I have these groups of donors:

- Small donor, gave < $100 in the past year.
- Medium donor, gave $100-500 in the past year.
- Major donor, gave > $500 in the past year.

What's the best way to get a count of all these in one place?  My best thought is to create smart groups - then I'd need a report of "Counts by Group".  Does such a thing exist?  What if I use aggregation with a Drupal View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGH Strategies has written a report to do this, which is available as an extension: [Donor Tier Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/donor-tier-report).

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [Summary fields Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields). Also, CiviCRM comes with a custom search (/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=2&reset=1) that would allow you to search for contacts that meet the criteria and create smart groups as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you!  However, my question isn't about how to create the smart groups.  Instead, it's how to run a report that has a `GROUP BY` using the groups.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would probably always use CiviRules (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) to do donor segmentation, allowing you to have groups to report on.

There is an example of donor segmentation with CiviRules on https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+Example+Donor+Classification

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would use Aggregation in Views - and I would base that on using Summary Fields extension.